# How to add a background color to a Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner here. I want to know how to add a background color to a Tkinter main window apart from `root.config(bg='black')`.

Comment: `root.config(bg='black')` should work.  If it does not work in your case, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
root['bg'] = 'color you want'
```

It works perfectly well. But I think the config method will be a better opinion.

Comment: The config method is not working for me. That is the reason I am using this method. Anyway, thanks, its working!